# Multiselect using semantic dropdown

Tags: dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm struggling to get a multi-select dropdown working with semantic ui.
A full example can be found here: https://jsbin.com/nowokulihi/edit?html,output
In the "toolbar" the first dropdown that is a single select is working fine, but the second that needs multiple selection does not work correctly.
I'm not looking for anything very sophisticated here, just the ability to (de)select each item in the list. Using checkboxes in a dropdown would also be OK (maybe better), but I can't find out how to do that. But it must be compact and play nicely in that toolbar.

```html
<div id="viewport" style="width:500px; height:400px;">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="ui labeled input">
        <span class="ui label">Colour:</span>
        <select class="ui compact dropdown" >
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>

        <span class="ui label">Display:</span>
        <select name="display" class="ui compact dropdown" multiple>
            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
            <option value="2">Item 2</option>
            <option value="3">Item 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main" style="height:100%">Get's displayed here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't create a javascript version of the Semantic UI's [Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) module, then the browser will use default `<select multiple>` behaviour, which is hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while you select and deselect your items.

Creating a javascript version will allow you to select your options in a more intuitive way as well as format the dropdowns to appear visually like other form elements, since the non-javascript version can appear quite crude.

[image: Dropdown - javascript version]

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<div class="ui labeled input">
  <span class="ui label">Colour:</span>
  <select class="ui compact dropdown" >
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <span class="ui label">Display:</span>
  <select name="display" class="ui dropdown" multiple>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's needed. 
The one thing of note is that running $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown() completely changes the hierarchy of the HTML elements, so selectors need to be a bit different from what you would expect from the initial hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, it will hide your initial dropdown element and inject it's own HTML into the DOM. However, you'll rarely need to change your selectors as you can either define callbacks or use [Behaviours](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#behavior) using the original selector.